How to quickly recover MariaDB 10 replication after restoring from backup
Firstoff my understanding of MySQL replication is rather rudimentary.
I have a backup taken of the master (with the DB shut down).  I have restored these files to the slave server and fixed the file permissions, and mysql starts.  The DB has all the data and queries are working.
I am however unable to get replication to run.  I get an error about the gtid_slave_pos table.  However this makes no sense to me, since gtid-mode is off.
Unable to load replication GTID slave state from mysql.gtid_slave_pos: Table 'mysql.gtid_slave_pos' doesn't exist"

I also get Duplicate Primary Key errors when I wait and run the show slave status command again.
How do I get replication back up?
P.S I can not make normal logical mysqldump backups - the DB takes more than a week to export and import.
